# JavaScript to PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

newbie question alert! :)

I am trying to convert this JavaScript that is loaded on the page to a PHP script as in IE 8 the values are not loaded.

This is the part of .js that I want to convert

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
 var user = loadCurrentUser();
 var user_id = user['user_id'];
 $('form[name="updateAccount"] input[name="email"]').val(user['email']);
```

I tired several versions of php code but nothing seems to be working.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You want to manipulate the DOM in PHP? That's really not going to work.

Comment: Maybe it would be possible to set the value of the email input to a certain users email using php. To find that out we should know what the `loadCurrentUser()` function does. But anyway, I'm sure the smarter way is to solve the IE8 issue.

Comment: Why not try using AJAX? You can use JavaScript to call a PHP function via AJAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply convert this JS snippet to PHP. Instead, you'll need to debug why this isn't working in IE8. I suspect it has something to do with the `loadCurrentUser()` function.